# How to solve this double integral analytically or numerically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-transforms

Can someone help me to solve this integral or explain me how to set it on mathematica?

\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dk_\alpha dk_\phi \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{k_\alpha^2}{2}} e^{-\frac{k_\phi^2}{2}} e^{ik_\alpha \alpha} e^{ik_\phi \phi} \xi^{ik_\alpha} e^{2i\sqrt{k_\alpha^2 - \xi k_\phi^2}} e^{-2i k_\alpha \ arctanh{ \Big(  \frac{\sqrt{k_\alpha^2 -  \xi k_\phi^2}}{k_\alpha}} \Big) } 
\end{equation}

I've tried both analytically and numerically but I couldn't solve it.
Analytically the calculation doesn't seem to go on, while numerically it returns several error messages.
Thank you all!

Comment: Post your code please, so we can see what went wrong...

Comment: Table[NIntegrate[
   1/(2 \[Pi]) Exp[-x^2/2] Exp[-y^2/2] Exp[I  2 x] Exp[
     I  2 y] p^(I x) Exp[
     2 I Sqrt[
       Abs[x^2 - p y^2]] Exp[-2 I x ArcTanh[
         Sqrt[Abs[x^2 - p y^2]]/x]]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}], {a, -50, 50, 0.2}, {f, -50, 50, 0.2}];

Comment: To use `NIntegrate`, `p` must be assigned a numeric value. Since `f` doesn't appear anywhere, should the iterator `{f, -50, 50, 0.2}` be for `p`?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: ok sorry I'm new here, thanks a lot to everyone